# I can't run Task Schedule in Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, schedule

I have an Laravel app in my localhost, with a command that makes me send an email. And it works perfect.
But when I pass it to my ubuntu 18.04 server, it runs, it doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't send the mail.
Does anyone know what the fault may be? Thank you

Comment: you can check laravel logs first.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing, but searching on google I found that there is a problem with putting: "php artisan schedule: run". So I ran: "php artisan" my command ", but now I have another problem hahaha. I throw this: **Swift_"TransportException  : Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465"**. I already changed everything to port 587 and tls encryption, and nothing, thank you

Comment: Hope you had resolved the issue by now. If not, please try to clear your config cache clear.
also check this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-config-swiftmailer-with-gmail 
and make sure you have correct ENV variables setup and config file.

Comment: I tried with mailtrap and it works correctly, so I'm going with mailgun, it looks like Gmail has problems with ubuntu. regards